# Verify Files in Local Machine is Up to Date with Dropbox server

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing a java app. i want to add feature to my app for verify files in my local dropbox folder is match with the files in dropbox server. how could i check my local dropbox folder is up to date ?

i found this on dropbox api. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta

but haven't idea about how to use it.

Comment: I imagine that if there are no "delta" entries returned, then you're up-to-date with the server.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL i don't know how to write a java program for check this.

Comment: Use the Java SDK. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk

Answer (score 1):

The /delta call is the best way to keep your app's state up to date with Dropbox (as long as you're interested in more than just one file or folder.) You've already found the docs:
    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta

There are also two posts with some notes from the beta period:
    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/announcements/15
    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/announcements/16

You can find the Java SDK here:
    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk
Inside the Java SDK, you'll find a working example app that uses /delta, named "SearchCache".

While the above resources will do a much better job explaining /delta, the basic idea is that when you first call it, you get the state of the Dropbox account, and on all subsequent calls, you get the "delta" of what you need to know to get up to date.